# I need my state to render on the first time but I only get the right value when like refreshing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I first get the products from firebase (I need the products for my local storage which takes a unique id for the collection). With this information if the product exists within localstorage and the user isnt loggedin I would then display it to the cart. I do get the correct information but not when i need it to display in the cart, it would just show empty until i refresh.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const getProducts = () => {
    const productsArray = []
    const path = `products-`

    categories.map((category) => {
      getDocs(collection(db, path + category.name))
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            productsArray.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
          })
          setProduct(productsArray)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          setErrorMsg(error.message)
        })
    })
  }

  getProducts()
}, [currentUser])

useEffect(() => {
  const getLocalCart = () => {
    if (!currentUser) {
      let productArray = []

      product.map((item) => {
        const storageItem = localStorage?.getItem('product' + item.id)
        if (storageItem) {
          productArray.push(JSON.parse(storageItem))
        }
      })
      setLocalCart(productArray)
    }
  }
  getLocalCart()
}, [])
```

Comment: 1.Please Format your code properly. First few lines are not clear.

Comment: 2. 'setLocalCart' is this setting to component state?

3. getLocalCart() what this function is doing?Is it  Trying to read the state set using setLocalCart?

Comment: Side note: declaring a constant function and calling it on the next line, without using it anywhere else, has exactly the same effect as running the inner code of the function inline. The differences are that assigning a const is slightly more verbose, increases the cyclomatic complexity by 1 and increases the memory consumption by an insignificant amount. In fewer words, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/gxtd6jzu/) would be a slightly better way to write your code.

Comment: I can't be sure without a *runnable* [mcve] but, most likely, you want to add `currentUser` to the dependencies array of the second `useEffect`.

Comment: @DattatreyaKugve sorry i dont usually post here and im also a newbie. But basically with getLocalCart() I am trying to get the localStorage data which has all the cart items and then i set local cart to that data which i can then pass down as a prop to display in cart.

Comment: @waldo Can you please put comments to your code describing the functionality at important lines. Also put the comments in problematic line

Comment: Also setLocalCart  and setProduct  are they state setting functions?.